# Very simple question, does a resistor have potential difference across it even when there is no current going through it?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

Assume a circuit with a battery, resistor, and capacitor in series. When the capacitor is full and no charge/current is going through the circuit, is there a potential difference across the resistor? (Assume the switch is closed.)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Well, of course you should just make your circuit and measure it!

As a textbook problem, and according to common measurement instruments, when resistor has no current through it, it has no potential across it (Ohm's law). With a sufficiently sensitive measuring device, you will observe a small, random thermal potential.

Comment: And a small random thermal current too.

Comment: @Dale Well, it depends on the measuring instrument. You'll get little current through a high impedance voltmeter, and little voltage across a low impedance ammeter.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming (as the symbol suggests) that your voltage source is DC, after a sufficiently long time has passed, the capacitor is fully charged and no current is flowing through the circuit. In this situation, if you were to measure the potential difference *across* the resistor, you would measure a zero value.

It is more instructive, however, to study the time evolution of voltage across the capacitor (or resistor) and the current through the circuit. To do this, you need to know the current-voltage relationship for a capacitor, write down a first order differential equation and solve it. This is a standard textbook exercise, but it is not absolutely necessary if the sole purpose is to answer the specific question that was posed.

A key thing to note, regardless, is that a capacitor resists an instantaneous change in voltage across itself. This fact governs the transient behavior of the circuit, for example, when the switch is closed. (Your question, is about the steady state behavior, or equivalently, the large time behavior.)

[This answer assumes various idealizations in the circuit element models. You can, of course, model some non-idealities using appropriate equivalent circuit models.]